# Excel Trend Lines on Categorical x value

Tags: microsoft-excel

When creating a trend line in Excel using categorical data in the x-axis, does Excel make an assumption about the values of 'x'?  Maybe, by assigning arbitrary values: 1, 2,..., n to the x categories?  For example, on the attached image, CAT=1, DOG=2,... FERRET=7.  Thus, Excel could then calculate a regression equation for (x,y).  [image: An illustrative trend line with animals as x-axis categories]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x values for that equation are:

[image]

So - doesn't make sense.

You can produce a line chart with a categorical x-axis. But it doesn't make sense to do so.

Similarly, you can produce a trend line on a line chart on a categorical axis. But it doesn't make sense to do so.

Comment: Thanks for solving for x and seeing what it does.. you are right.  what excel is doing is nonsense.  Self-disappointed as I didn’t think of doing this.  Thanks again!